# How to make a dynamic select option with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have this two selects 'country' and 'university' that receives data from the database, the university select  changes its options according to the country that is selected.

but the university select only changes with some of the countries and not all of them, it changes only with the first ids of the countries.

i'm doing it with javascript change function

this is my controller

```
 $country =  DB::table('country')
            ->select('id as id_country', 'desc_country as description')
            ->get();

 $university= DB::table('university')
            ->select('id_country','id as id_university', 'description')
            ->get();
```

and this is my view

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
<label for="sku">Country:</label>
<select class="form-control selectpicker" id="countryuni" name="id_country" data-live-search="true">
<option value="" selected="true">Select an option</option>    
@foreach($country as $cou)
<option value="{{ $cou->id_country}}">{{ $cou->description}}</option>
 @endforeach
</select>
</div>




<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
<label for="sku">University:</label>
<select  id="universityc" class="form-control" name="id_university" required="true">
<option value="" selected="true">Select an option</option>  
 @foreach($university as $uni)
<option value="{{ $uni->id_country}}_{{ $uni->id_university}}">{{ $uni->description}}</option>
@endforeach
</select>
</div>




<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $("#countryuni").change(function() {
        var filter = $(this).val();
        $("#a").append('a');
        $('select#universityc option').each(function() {
          $("#a").append('a');
          var area2 = $(this).val().split('_');
          //alert();
          if (area2[0] == filter) {
            $(this).show();
          } else {
            $(this).hide();
          }
        });
        var var1 = $('#universityc').val(filter);
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: *"but the university select only changes with some of the countries and not all of them"* ...... The other countries that you don't want the university changes when you select them, do you want to keep all the universities of all the countries show when you select these countries ?

Comment: @Accountantم no, when i select for example 'Canada' it lists only the universities of canada and the rest of universities don't appear, but like i said it only change with some countries

Comment: OK I understand this part, what about the other countries that you don't want to change university with ? what happens to the university select then ? should it has all the universities options then ?

Comment: it has, but i'm trying not to show all the options because it overloads the memory.

Comment: Give me an example : if the user selects `Canada` you narrow down the universities options, if he select other country that don't change universities e.g `China` , **you show all the universities ? , or you just keep it as the last narrowed options from previous country Canada ?**

Comment: no, if the user selects a country that don't change the university, the select option from university shows empty and blank

Comment: OK, I got it , how many universities do you have ? (the total number of them)

Comment: like 9229 records